# Raster Files Sizes from Point Data Extremely Different

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, dem

Using ArcGIS 10.1.

I created rasters from several groups of point rasters using the Point to Raster tool.  All of the points groups are similar size and extents.  The first group of points had a file size of 250MB.  The other groups of points had a give size of about 900GB each. All of them are GRID float point files.

Comment: do you have the same pixel size and the same compression ?

Comment: I would output to .img format rather than grid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be down to extents of your input data. You say they are *similar* extents that sounds a bit subjective to me. If you look at the point to raster tool help file you will see that it honours the [extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000007000000) environment setting. Try setting that to a common extent that you want for all your rasters.

Another thing to check is: do all you input point layers have sensible coordinates? If the data is coming out of a text file or *evil* Excel then null rows may get given a 0,0. A single point at that location cannot be seen say at the extent of your data so something has to fill in all that space and it will be nodata values. This would increase the size of the data.

One final check is you say the output is float, well you can be 32bit or 64bit.